# Openning phpmyadmin without errors

Tags: php, web, phpmyadmin, webserver

I set the following variables in php.ini though I still could not find the place where the variables are set

```
Server environment  Bitrix Virtual Appliance version 4.2 or higher  Unknown environment

Processing .htaccess    Enabled                                     Disabled
```

I just changed the values

```
date.timezone = "Europe / Moscow"

mbstring.func_overload = 2
```

But when installing 1s bitrix, you need to specify the database I created.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urSDm.png)

When you open http: // localhost / pma, a message appears on the screen

Deprecated :

> The mbstring.func_overload directive is deprecated in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error :

> Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Overloading of string functions using mbstring.func_overload is not supported by phpseclib. in C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\bootstrap.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(66): require() #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(56): composerRequirec1a85a0e014f9e891c8f3df09ff040e3('decc78cc4436b12...', 'C:\Apache24\htd...') #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitc1a85a0e014f9e891c8f3df09ff040e3::getLoader() #3 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\libraries\common.inc.php(91): require_once('C:\Apache24\htd...') #4 C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\index.php(27): require_once('C:\Apache24\htd...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\pma\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\bootstrap.php on line 11

Comment: What php version do you use?
It seems like 1S is quite old for this version.

Comment: I use php version 7.3.6 @MaxShayan

Comment: Find 1S documentation. I guess they don't support this version, as your php version is the last one.

Comment: Can you set `mbstring.func_overload` to 0? Why does it need to be 2?